# Can you skip az login in terraform init, for a terraform pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am currently building a terraform pipeline, where the steps are as follows:

1. Setting the environment
2. terraform init
3. terraform plan
4. terraform apply

At the current stage I want to perform terraform init without doing az login and not use az login  . I am doing this on azure dev ops and was wondering how I can achieve?

Comment: How do you expect to do this through Azure DevOps if you don’t authenticate to Azure itself? How will Azure know who you are and what account/subscription to spawn the resources under?

Answer (score 1):

You need to authenticate yourself to Azure, otherwise Terraform would never know where to place it's resources (in which subscription, which resource group and with which rights).

You can also opt using a Managed Service Identity or Service Principal with a Client Certificate.

All information regarding this you can find on the official [Terraform documentation here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret)